# UITapgestureRecogniser in tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell` which displays a phone number. When I click it I should be able to make call to that particular number. So for making it clickable I have added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it .But I couldn't get how to refer the which tap is clicked, I mean which number was clicked.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    lblphone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGSizeMake(20,30,50,100)];
    lblphone.tag = 116;
    lblphone.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblphone.text=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@",phone];
    [lblphone setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
    [lblphone setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [lblphone setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelButton:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [lblphone addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [tapGestureRecognizer release];
    [cell addSubview:lblphone];
}

-(IBAction)labelButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *phoneno = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:116];
    NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phoneno.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

But everytime I could see the phonenumber of last cell in `NSString *phoneNumber`;

How can I refer which label is clicked in `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: why did you use a "`UILabel`" instead of a "`UIButton`" ??

Comment: I tried it for UILabel...

Comment: try this UILabel *phoneno = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:[tapGestureRecognizer.view.tag]];

Comment: Is there any reason you specifically need to you a `UILabel` instead of a `UIButton`? You can make a `UIButton` look exactly like your `UILabel` looks and it handles all of the functionality it looks as through your trying to achieve by default. You would just hook all of the button presses up to a single handler and determine which one was pressed using the exact same method to what you are now. Handling touch events is what the `UIButton` is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lblphone.tag = indexPath.row + 1;` instead of  `lblphone.tag = 116;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Also you can achieve this without using the tags.

**See Example below**

```
-(void)labelButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{
   UILabel *phoneno = (UILabel *) tapGestureRecognizer.view;
}
```

Comment: I followed 2nd way because its gets easily replaced with my code.Got it .Thank u...